# Move work item alone from Team Project of one collection to another collection

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Can I move a work item alone from one Team project collection to another collection in TFS 2018?

Comment: Adding in the second and deleting in the first is one way to do it. But do you want to preserve the history?

Comment: Do I need to manually add and delete?

Answer (score 0):

You can't move it. Team project collections are intended to be totally separate. However, you can **re-create** it with the same information. That is a manual activity, or you can use the REST APIs to do so.

Comment: Can you please share the REST API's if any?

Comment: You can look up the REST API documentation, which is easily located.

Answer (score 0):

"WI Migrator" helps to migrate work item from one team collection to another.